# Userena set password after activation automatic signin

Tags: django, django-users

My users will be able to create users for their clients, which will send an activation email to them.

With userena, the activation link will automatically log them in, even without a password being set.

I have got to this point, where they are logged in. Now they need to set a password, and it seems they need to know their old password to do that.

What I would like is for the client user to be prompted to set their password as part of the activation process.

Where would be the best place to start with that?

Answer (score 1):

Userena [doesn't have an invite](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/issues/126) function, you'll have to [override views](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19777151073/how-to-override-a-view-from-an-external-django-app) to change the behaviour of the password setting.  I created an app to extend userena where I override the activate view of userena in my project urls.py .

```
    url(r'^accounts/activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$', create_userpass),
```

where my custom view "create_userpass" is a form where the user changes the password and username (without necessary previous knowledge of either) before the account is successfully activated.

I also use a custom invite form which contains only an EmailField, where a temporary username and password are auto-generated (never seen by anyone), which are those replaced by the new user during activation.  The invite form's save method has this at the end, which creates the new userena user.

```
        new_user = UserenaSignup.objects.create_user(username,
                                                 email,
                                                 password,
                                                 not userena_settings.USERENA_ACTIVATION_REQUIRED,
                                                 userena_settings.USERENA_ACTIVATION_REQUIRED)
    return new_user
```

I will put the app on github soon and share the link here.

Comment: Sorry did not, it's rather specific to the application and not so intuitive to make a generic app, but it's on my list to create a blog post example.  Anymore details you need though Im happy to provide here in SO.

Comment: A link to your blog post when you write it might be nice.